# Binary Serialization (Save and load)

Tags: c#, binary

My question is, i used this structure of **binary serialization** in an old program using the same format of saving and loading a list of objects. In the new program im not receiving any errors, and upon running the program and going into the save function, it catches the exception and states "unable to save file". There is some form of data being saved when i manually open the .Txt file but upon running the program again the data is not loaded back in. I am just wondering if someone could take a few minutes to look over the code and see if there is anything i'm missing.

edit* i have now included the display class that holds the list of classrooms and the classroom class. Hope this helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ExamAssignment
{
[Serializable]
public class SaveLoad
{

    public void Save(string filename, List<Classroom> objsave)                   
    {
        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //point to the file's location 
        string strFileLocation = "SAVE.xml";
        // Gain code access to the file that we are going `
        // to write to 
        try
        {

            // Create a FileStream that will write data to file. 
            FileStream writerFileStream = new FileStream(strFileLocation,             FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            binFormatter.Serialize(writerFileStream, objsave);
            // Close the writerFileStream when we are done. 
            writerFileStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to save the file");
        }        
    }

    public List<Classroom> Load()
    {
        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string strFileLocation = "SAVE.xml";// Check if we had previously Saved Results previously 
        List<Classroom> objLoad = new List<Classroom>();

        if (File.Exists(strFileLocation))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a FileStream will gain read access to the data file. 
                FileStream readerFileStream = new FileStream(strFileLocation, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);// Reconstruct information of the Results from file. 
                objLoad = (List<Classroom>)
                binFormatter.Deserialize(readerFileStream);
                // Close the readerFileStream when we are done 
                readerFileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There seems to be a file that contains the Classrooms but somehow there is a problem " + "with reading it.");// end try-catch 
            }
        }
        return objLoad;
        // end if
```

..

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ExamAssignment
{
[Serializable]
public class Display
{

    Classroom C1 = new Classroom();
    public List<Classroom> ClassList;
    SaveLoad objSave = new SaveLoad();


    public Display()
    {

        ClassList = new List<Classroom>();


    }


    public void saving()
    {

        objSave.Save("SAVE.xml", ClassList);


    }

    public void Load()
    {

        ClassList = objSave.Load();


    }




    public void addClassroom()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the number of the classroom");

        int ClassNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nNow enter the module of the classroom");

        string ClassModule = Console.ReadLine();


        ClassList.Add(new Classroom(ClassNum, ClassModule));

        for (int i = 0; i < ClassList.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nClass Number: {0}, Class Module: {1}", ClassNum, ClassModule);

        }



    }

    public void ViewClass()

    {


        Console.WriteLine("To view the students and teacher in a classroom please enter the class number");

        int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int index = ClassList.FindIndex(item => selection == item.ClassNum);

        ClassList[index].ViewClassroom();




    }

    public void ViewClassrooms()

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ClassList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nClass Number: {0}, Class Module: {1}", ClassList[i].ClassNum, ClassList[i].ClassModule);

        }


    }


    public void AddStudent()
    {
        int repeat = 0;
        int RoomNumber = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please state the room number you wish to add the students to");

        RoomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int index = ClassList.FindIndex(item => RoomNumber == item.ClassNum);

        do
        {

            ClassList[index].AddStudent();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, to add another student to the classroom press 1, or to exit press 0");

        repeat = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        }
        while (repeat == 1);
    }

    public void removeStudent()
    {
        int RoomNumber = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease state the room number you wish to remove the teacher from");

        RoomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int index = ClassList.FindIndex(item => RoomNumber == item.ClassNum);

        ClassList[index].RemoveStudent();


    }

    public void AddModule()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ViewModule()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void AddTeacher()
    {


        int repeat = 0;
        int RoomNumber = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please state the room number you wish to add the Teacher to");

        RoomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int index = ClassList.FindIndex(item => RoomNumber == item.ClassNum);

        do
        {

            ClassList[index].AddTeacher();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, to add another teacher to a classroom press 1, or to exit press 0");

        repeat = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        while (repeat == 1);

    }

        public void removeTeacher()
        {

            int RoomNumber = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease state the room number you wish to remove the teacher from");

            RoomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int index = ClassList.FindIndex(item => RoomNumber == item.ClassNum);

            ClassList[index].RemoveTeacher();


        }



}
```

}

```
namespace ExamAssignment
{

[Serializable]
public class Classroom
{
    private int classNum;
    private string classModule;
    public Teacher t1;
    public List<Student> ClassStudents;
    public Display d1;
    public int selection;



    public Classroom(int newClassNum, string newClassModule)
    {

        ClassStudents = new List<Student>();
        Display d1 = new Display();

        classNum = newClassNum;
        classModule = newClassModule;
        //selection = Newselection;

    }

    public Classroom()
    {





    }


    public void AddStudent()
    {


            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Student Name");
            string stuName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Now enter the student Id");
            int stuNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            ClassStudents.Add(new Student(stuName, stuNum));


            for (int i = 0; i < ClassStudents.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nStudent Name: {0}, Student ID: {1}", ClassStudents[i].Name, ClassStudents[i].StudentId);

            }


    }

    public void AddTeacher()
    {



        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Teacher's name to add to the classroom");

        string teachName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the Teacher ID");

        int teachNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        t1 = new Teacher(teachNum, teachName);



    }


    public void RemoveStudent()
    {

        int loop = 0;

        do
        {

            int j = 0;
            int selection = 0;



            for (int i = 0; i < ClassStudents.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nStudent Name: {0}, Student ID: {1}, {2}", ClassStudents[i].Name, ClassStudents[i].StudentId, j);
                j = j + 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nTo remove a student please choose a number from the list or press 99 to exit");

            selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (selection < 98)
            {

                loop = 1;

            }

            else
            {

                ClassStudents.RemoveAt(selection); 

            }
        }
        while (loop == 0);


    }


    public void RemoveTeacher()
    {

        int repeat = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nTeacher name:{0}, Teacher ID {1}\n", t1.name, t1.staffId);

            Console.WriteLine("To remove this teacher press 1 or to go back to the menu press 0");

            int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (selection == 1)
            {

                t1 = null;
                Console.WriteLine("\n Thank you, this teacher has been removed\n");

            }

            if (selection == 0)
            {

                repeat = 0;


            }

        }

        while (repeat == 1);

    }

    public void ViewClassroom()
    {


        if (ClassStudents != null)
        {
            foreach (Student s1 in ClassStudents)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n" + s1.name + " " + s1.studentId);
            }
        }


        if (t1 != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nTeacher name: {0}, Teacher ID {1}\n", t1.name, t1.staffId);

        }

        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("there is no teacher associated with this classroom");

        }


    }

    public Teacher One
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public Student Many
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public Module onE
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    } 


    public int ClassNum
    {
        get
        {
            return classNum;
        }
        set
        {
            value = classNum;
        }
    }

    public string ClassModule
    {
        get
        {
            return classModule;
        }
        set
        {
            value = classModule;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `catch (Exception) { Console.WriteLine("Unable to save the file"); }` 100% useless code. You should inspect your exceptions, not mask them with meaningless errors.

Comment: Sorry, im only a beginner programmer, been doing c# for about 5 months now, just using it as a simple save and load system

Comment: You need to print actual error, at least `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", ex); }` you will easily figure out what exactly doesn't work

Comment: Ok after following your guidance, im getting somewhere, that is really helpful being able to see the error. i feel so stupid now. the error im receiving is that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. says something about String maybeFullPath??

Answer (score 1):

Mark your class with the [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute as this is required for serialization of classes with `BinaryFormatter`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Classroom
{
    /*...your class definition...*/
}
```

Comment: I have done this for all the classes, still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please share your code for classroom class, to better help you.